# Input field with a remove button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a bootstrap 3 input field have a little close icon appended on the top right of the input.

Here's my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/8konLjur/

There's 2 problems with this though:

1. The `&times;` symbol isn't correctly placed in the circle.
2. I'm trying to move the `<a></a>` circle so it's halfway on the input border underneath and above (does that make sense?). This might have to be done with absolute positioning or javascript, I don't know.

Comment: Did you read this? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: @MaxBaldwin, Yes, but that's not really the desired look. The button ideally shouldn't be the same height as the input, it should be smaller and attached to the top right corner.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way would be to wrap the input in a div and set its position to relative and set the icon absolute relative to that:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aminmeyghani/upy5cLgf/3/)

`<div style="position: relative"> <!-- absolute relative to parent --> </div>`

BUT, when working with bootstrap try to look at the patterns rather than hacking your way through.

Comment: Muhambi - in order to position the teal circle the way you want it, just change the top attribute in Amin's post from 10px to -5px and you'll have the element "centered" on the border of the input element.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `btn` class for style and position it with additional class.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
  &times;
</button>
```

or

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

See the example here below the icon section: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons

Answer (score 1):

In your `btn-close` make the following:

```
.btn-close {
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    background: teal;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    float: right;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And it is better to enclose the input field and the close button in a div. Checkout this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8konLjur/4/).